# Appearing and Disappearing UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I'm new to Objective C and swift (I guess we are all new to swift) but I am trying to make a UIButton appear and disappear in different locations on the screen in my app. This is what I've tried in one of my view controllers so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
func addButton() {
  var start: CFTimeInterval
  var elapsedTime:CFTimeInterval
  let Button = UIButton()
  let picture = UIImage(named: "picture.png")
  Button.setImage(picture, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  Button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 142, 106.6, 106.5)
  self.view!.addSubview(Button)
  while (elapsedTime < 1.0) {
      elapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - start
  }
  Button.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

Comment: You should use an [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:) instead of a while loop - I'm pretty sure the while loop blocks your UI thread, and as a result it never actually gets rendered to the screen

Answer (score 1):

You could use the convenient GCD API for the timing

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t(1.0), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    button.removeFromSuperView()
})
```

If it is always the same button, it would be better to create a variable or outlet and just recycle the button (you just let it appear and disappear by setting the `alpha` or the `hidden` property. If it is just supposed to be blinking, you could use a basic `CAAnimation`s instead.

NB: Please get into the habit of using variable names that start with small letters, or you will end up mistaking them for class names.

Comment: I understand what you did here but when I added this line to my function, it doesn't display the button at all

Comment: Start by commenting out your code that makes he button go away. Debug your code that adds a button first. Then go back and debug the code that removes the button.